# Using SmptClient to send email from gmail account fails for specific account only

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I'm using SmptClient to send email from a gmail account. This account sends lots of emails every day (sort of a support@mydomain.com automatic emails)

All was working fine until it suddenly stopped working. I didn't change anything in my application nor did i deploy a new version.

When i try a regular SmptClient example code it gives me this error message:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
```

If i change only the fromAddress and fromPassword to a different account, without changing anything else in the code, the code works!

Here's the sample code which i'm using: (The code if fine becuase it does work for a different account)

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("****", "****");
                var toAddress = new MailAddress("****", "****");
                const string fromPassword = "****";
                const string subject = "testing... ";
                const string body = "body test";

                var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
                    Timeout = 20000
                };
                var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = body
                };


                    smtp.Send(message);
```

When i connect to gmail using the invalid account and send an email, it does work.
It seems as if the SMTP server is failing to authenticate.

I connected to the list of **Gmail Latest Account Activity**  and it didn't show the connection attempts i made from code. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the the POP/IMAP access for the account was disabled?

Comment: Its Gmail. Is there a way to check it so i know for sure? When i connect to the account on gmail.com emails are being sent just fine, can this still be the issue?

Comment: Yes, you could [enable/disable POP/IMAP access](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?rd=1&hl=en#ts=1665119) to a given gmail account. If you are using google apps email, then maybe this [article](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=105694) could help.

Comment: But... What does it have to do with POP / IMAP ?? i'm sending the email through smtp.gmail... ???

Comment: Good point :) I thought this options control also the send access. Then maybe this [article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en) could help. There are a few check points.